# SublimeText disable ruler on console

Tags: sublimetext

I use ruler on SublimeText at column 80.

But it also shows up in the SublimeText console (actually a little to the left). Can we hide the ruler here?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That does not look like the console; the console in Sublime has an input widget along the bottom for you to enter console commands into.

That looks instead like a [Terminus](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Terminus) panel instead.

If that's the case, if you use `Preferences > Package Settings > Terminus > Settings` to open the settings window, you can add the following setting to turn off rules (or alternately, set them to some other value, etc)

```json
    "view_settings":
    {
        // "font_face": "Iosevka Term SS09",
        "rulers": []
    },
```

The settings in this object are applied to all terminus views that open; so you can as seen in this example, also change the `font_face`, `font_size` or other settings specific to the Terminus window.

As a side note, the reason the ruler doesn't line up the same spot in the console as it does above is that the console doesn't have a `gutter` area in  it, so it doesn't have as much horizontal space.

Comment: My next question was going to be how to add colors to the "console". But Terminus is the answer already.